# Website that only loads content on modal windows (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working with a client that only loves Wordpress, so I have to create a theme. The idea of my client is to have an interactive background (meaning there's no other content but the background, the menu and the company logo) which creates a water effect, that's already done.

Now, he wants the content to be loaded in modal windows so my first option was using ajax and so far it is working great. The only problem right now is that he wants his users to use the browser's back button (which means using pushState) and I think that later he will want to open this modals via url (http://website.com/products and the products modal appears without clicking on the menu).

All the content is created in HTML files, so I'm not using Wordpress pages at all. **What would you guys do in my situation?** I've never done something like this so I'm a little lost

Comment: Modal windows are evil.  Fortunately, it's a self-defeating strategy since any sane consumer runs with pop-up blockers.  What would I do?  Convince the client to go another direction.

Comment: Oh no, I don't mean a pop up (like when ads or something) I mean an in-page modal/dialog window @CPerkins